# SvelteKit navigation issue: client-side change detection not working

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am in the process of developing a dashboard using SvelteKit and am encountering an issue with handling page navigation in scenarios where the use of an anchor tag is not possible.

To elucidate, I have a "month picker" implemented on my dashboard. The functionality I'm trying to achieve is such that whenever a user selects a month, they get redirected to the corresponding page using the `goto` function from `$app/navigation`. For instance, if a user is currently on the `/expenses/july` route and opts for 'June' via the month picker, the aim is to redirect them to `/expenses/june`.

As expected, this redirection triggers the load function of the page. However, I'm facing a perplexing issue **on the client-side where no changes are detected**.

Specifically, the data encapsulated in `export let data: PageData` remains constant! No alterations are discerned despite the page redirection. I'm trying to understand why this anomaly is occurring and how I can resolve it. Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some code examples in question so that we can better help you with your issue.

Comment: How did you determine that `data` did not change?

Answer (score 2):

I now understand the root of my issue. It seems I was inadvertently maintaining the data object attributes as unchanging, due to the way I was assigning them to new variables. For example, this is how I was doing it:

```
export let data: PageData;
let { year, month } = data;
$: console.log(month);
```

In this setup, the console.log only gets triggered on a full page refresh, rather than upon every navigation event.

Now, I realize that I should have used a reactive declaration for my year and month variables to make sure they are updated every time data changes, like this:

```
export let data: PageData;
let { year, month } = data;
$: ({ year, month } = data);
$: console.log(month);
```

Doing so, the reactive block will be re-evaluated every time data is updated, ensuring year and month always reflect the most recent values.

Thank you for your help.